# absolute path to file in classic asp using

Tags: asp-classic

how to use absolute paths with classic asp? at the moment the whole application has the following includes of files:

```
<!--#include file="../../../../../something.asp"-->
```

It doesn't work if I do a absolute call to the asp file like:

```
<!--#include file="/root/foobar/something.asp"-->
```

Someone knows a trick to let it work?

Answer (score 2):

Use [virtual paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525940%28VS.90%29.aspx), which are based off the website root:

```
<!--#include virtual="/something.asp"-->
```

Comment: Worth to mention that in case of free hosts, one sometimes need to add the username in the beginning in case the host has multiple sites e.g. `<!--#include virtual="/hostusername/something.asp"-->`.

Answer (score 0):

The first example will work if the site settings are changed in IIS to "**Allow parent paths**".

The second sample is not acceptible, at least not on Windows servers.

Comment: Please explain why the second sample is wrong, just saying "it's wrong" is not really helpful.